# Seaborn pairplot: how to change legend label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I'm making a simple pairplot with Seaborn in Python that shows different levels of a categorical variable by the color of plot elements across variables in a Pandas DataFrame. Although the plot comes out exactly as I want it, the categorical variable is binary, which makes the legend quite meaningless to an audience not familiar with the data (categories are naturally labeled as 0 & 1).

An example of my code:

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, hue='categorical_var', palette='Set3')
```

Is there a way to change legend label text with pairplot? Or should I use PairGrid, and if so how would I approach this?

Comment: Why is 0 and 1 a natural labeling for the categories? Why not use meaningful names?

Comment: Because I will need the numerical values for analysis later on.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit seaborn legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201514/edit-seaborn-legend)

Answer (score 1):

Found it! It was answered here: [Edit seaborn legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201514/edit-seaborn-legend/45211976)

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, hue='categorical_var', palette='Set3')
g._legend.set_title(new_title)
```

Comment: This code changes the legend title, not the legend labels. But the linked question does concern the labels, so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide a full example of code, nor mock data, I will use my own codes to answer.

**First solution**

The easiest must be to keep your binary labels for analysis and to create a column with proper names for plotting. Here is a sample code of mine, you should grab the idea:

```
def transconum(morph):
    if (morph == 'S'):
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 0.0

CompactGroups['MorphNum'] = CompactGroups['MorphGal'].apply(transconum)
```

**Second solution**

Another way would be to overwrite labels on the flight. Here is a sample code of mine which works perfectly:

```
grid = sns.jointplot(x="MorphNum", y="PropS", data=CompactGroups, kind="reg")
grid.set_axis_labels("Central type", "Spiral proportion among satellites")
grid.ax_joint.set_xticks([0, 1, 1])
plt.xticks(range(2), ('$Red$', '$S$'))
```

Comment: just a comment to your first solution: can be reduced into a list comprehension `CompactGroups['MorphNum'] = [1 if i == True else 0 for i in CompactGroups['MorphGal'] == 'S']`