# How can I remove the Seaborn FacetGrid's legend title?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using Seaborn's FacetGrid to combine many plots in one figure and I want to remove the legend title. For instance, in the example below, I want to remove the title "sex".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col= 'day')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'total_bill', 'tip', 'sex', ci = False)    
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

I am aware of the discussion how to change the title in, e.g., [How can I change the Seaborn FacetGrid's legend title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633621/how-can-i-change-the-seaborn-facetgrids-legend-title) However, I have not seen how to remove the legend title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the hack provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57633733/4932316) answer by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) and it works for your purpose

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips.columns = [n if n != "sex" else "" for n in tips.columns]

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col= 'day')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'total_bill', 'tip', '', ci = False)    
leg = g.add_legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that works. Seems like there should be a non-hacking way of doing it, but I guess not.