# Seaborn - change legend section headings for a plot with multiple visual aesthetics

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to change the section headings of my plot legend. For the example below they read: 'smoker' and 'time' but let's say I want them to read 'Smoker' and 'Time of Day' respectively.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips=sns.load_dataset('tips')

sns.relplot(
    data=tips,
    x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='smoker', style='time'
)

plt.show()
```

Any tips?

### Edits

Thanks for linking: [How to edit a seaborn legend title and labels for figure-level functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201514/how-to-edit-a-seaborn-legend-title-and-labels-for-figure-level-functions)

I had only skimmed through it. After spending some more time with it, it still hasn't answered my question. The main difference being I want to change the subtitle values within a legend, rather than the legend title or the label values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips=sns.load_dataset('tips')

g = sns.relplot(
    data=tips,
    x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='smoker', style='time',
    facet_kws={'legend_out': True}
)

# can only set the title of the entire legend, not the subtitles
g._legend.set_title('Legend')
plt.show()
```

If a diagram is more helpful:

[image]

red = what I want to change (not answered by [How to edit a seaborn legend title and labels for figure-level functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201514/how-to-edit-a-seaborn-legend-title-and-labels-for-figure-level-functions))
yellow = what is answered by [How to edit a seaborn legend title and labels for figure-level functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201514/how-to-edit-a-seaborn-legend-title-and-labels-for-figure-level-functions)

Comment: Change the values in the columns with `.map`

Comment: In regards to the edit, the easiest option is to rename the columns, since that's where the name comes from. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11346283/7758804

Comment: `sns.relplot(data=tips.rename(columns={'smoker':'Smoker', 'time':'Time of Day'}), x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='Smoker', style='Time of Day')`
is a fine workaround, yes. Thank you